# Content List vs Administer nodes

Tags: routes

New Drupal and playing with permissions. I can't figure out how to get a content list or something similar if the Administer Nodes permission has been disabled.

I'm trying to restrict a user role, strip down the admin menu, e.g. remove 'Post Settings' under content management.

I have a feeling I'm doing this wrong, so my question is: Can I create a user menu, same as the admin menu without certain links and how?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to create a list of all the nodes on the site and make sure the role has access to see it. This is by far the simplest and quickest way of implementing such a feature.

A more complex way would be to [alter the menu link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/7) and change it's access control but I wouldn't recommend doing this.